# Horizontal line in the middle of divs

Tags: html, css

I want to make a line in the middle of the divs. In the following image, the line should be in the middle of the red boxes.

[image]

I'm trying to do that using the line height, but not able to.

Here's the code:

**HTML/CSS:**

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
.links {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  height: 1px;
  line-height: 0.1em;
}
.dot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 150px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="links">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/nkq468xg/

Comment: why cant you just use border-top on links instead of line-height

Comment: Check your code snippet in your question here on SO ("Run code snippet" blue button), is that what you need? Added `position: relative;
  top: -10px;` in your code for `.dot`. https://jsfiddle.net/nkq468xg/3/

Comment: you may use a 1pixel  background image to draw the line and eventually use inline-block instead float: https://jsfiddle.net/nkq468xg/4/

Comment: this might be helpful https://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/Irlpm

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` on `links` and for line you can use `:before` pseudo-element on wrap element.

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.links {
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.dot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="links">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one where the line is actually on top, but it does add another element to the HTML:

https://jsfiddle.net/nkq468xg/2/

```css
.wrap {
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 20px; 
}
.links { 
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
hr {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}
.dot {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="links">
    <hr>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Adding HTML elements should ***always*** be the last resort. Here, it is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: Depends if you need the line on top or below the boxes.

Comment: No, in this case neither requires additional markup.

Comment: It does. Did you even check it?

Comment: The jsfiddle.net one, yes. It does not work, it seems

Comment: Brilliant answer - it gave me an idea how to do it

Answer (score 5):

You can use pseudo element, like `::after`

```
.links {
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: auto; // Your div will have the height of the overflowing elements
}

.links::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the `top` (my markup seems a bit different) to make it work. The double colon was wrong, so I've edited the answer - `:after` instead of `::after`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. However I have to disagree with your edit. The double coulon wasn't a mistake. If you read the docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements#syntax), you'll see that   *As a rule, double colons (::) should be used instead of a single colon (:). This distinguishes pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements. However, since this distinction was not present in older versions of the W3C spec, most browsers support both syntaxes for the original pseudo-elements.*

Comment: sorry about that - I've reverted my edit! (and changed it in my own code)

Comment: @Risadinha To be honest, we used to use a single colon to support IE8 and below. I'll edit my answer as in the first line I've use only one colon myself... :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your code snippet in your question here on SO ("Run code snippet" blue button), is that what you need? 
Added `position: relative; top: -10px;` in your code for `.dot`.

```
.dot {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nkq468xg/3/